# Firebird - Connection Refused

Tags: 13.10, connection, remote-access, telnet

Whenever I try to connect firebird on my Ubuntu 13.10 from my Window 7 computer I get an error message saying that the connection was refused.

I'm trying to connect using IBExpert and Java. Java throws a FBSQLException saying:

```
GDS Exception. 33554721. Unable to complete network request to host '10.1.1.8'
```

I was able to connect once then I restarted my Ubuntu just to be sure that it'd keep working but after I restarted it it's not working anymore.

I did

```
telnet localhost
```

and I received the following message:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1  
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I'm able to ping from my Ubuntu to my Windows and from my Windows to Ubuntu with no problem and I'm able to share file between them using samba without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Firebird port is closed by default

You need to modify  RemoteBindAddress in /etc/firebird/2.5/firebird.conf

from

> RemoteBindAddress = localhost

to

> RemoteBindAddress =

also telnet neets to be for port 3050

> telnet localhost 3050

more about securing firebird on ubuntu

http://mapopa.blogspot.ro/2011/04/securing-firebird-25-superclassic-in.html